# Select button by value

Tags: jquery

How do I select a button with specific value with jQuery?

```
<input type="button" value="My task">
```

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You can use the `attr=value` [selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/):

```
$('input[type="button"][value="My task"]')
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/niklasvh/yAUkC/

Answer (score 7):

Like:

```
$('input[type=button][value=My task]');
```

You want to select by attributes: [jQuery page](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/).

So it says: select `input`s of type `button` with value `My task`.

Answer (score 6):

Just another approach, useful in some exceptional cases where value and text inside `<button>` element is different

```
<button value="Value X">Value Y</button>
$("button:contains(Value Y)")
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I was here to find out this problem's solution.

Answer (score 5):

If prgmrDevs solution doesn't work for you this worked for me!

$(':button[value="Value X"]')

Comment: Explanation: this is for the case where you are using the `<button>` element. Works perfectly.

Answer (score 3):

The suggestions here are great! 
I'd like just to show you what you can also do:
let's say you have this:

```
<input type="button" value="My task">
<input type="button" value="Your task">
<input type="button" value="Our job">
<input type="button" value="Their job">
```

and you want to get the values that have the word *'task'* you can do it like:

```
$('input[type=button][value~=task]')
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/roXon/geZau/1/)